ProtonVPN no longer connects76 after uninstalling a different VPN (Cisco AnyConnect)
Problem:
I usually use ProtonVPN (free tier) on MacOS without a hitch. Recently I downloaded a VPN from my university (Cisco AnyConnect). I later uninstalled AnyConnect. I must have messed with something because now ProtonVPN doesn't work. Specifically, ProtonVPN tries to connect to a server but is never able to complete the connection and eventually gives up.
What I've tried so far:

I restarted my Macbook
I uninstalled ProtonVPN and redownloaded it
I flushed my DNS using the instructions here: https://protonvpn.com/support/flush-dns-cache
I deleted the ProtonVPN configuration in System Settings and then had ProtonVPN "recreate" a configuration (I turned on ProtonVPN and then it requested to add a configuration).

Other observations:

I downloaded another free VPN (Windscribe) and it works flawlessly so the problem seems to be exclusive to ProtonVPN?
In System Settings in VPN, ProtonVPN is there but the slider is Disconnected. When I try to turn the slider on, it refuses to move. When I click the i for Info it shows that the "Connect on Demand" setting is on.
Just a note but Windscribe doesn't show up in the VPN section of System settings (but still works?).


Cisco VPN leaves stuff behind, you can't just trash the app. If you still have access to the installer download see if it has an uninstall button or menu item or if there is a dedicated uninstaller. Once Anyconnect is totally and completely gone You can likely use ProtonVPN
